# Entry box inside toplevel window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a code to show Entry widget inside top-level window in tkinter but it is not showing anything when I run it.
Below is the code from where I am calling the top-level window:

```
#file: app.py

# enter new racer
btnNewRacer = Button(app, text = "Enter New Racer", style = 'W.TButton', command = EnterRacer)
btnNewRacer.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 50, padx = 50)
```

And this is the code where I have written the code for Entry widget:

```
#file: new_racer.py

def EnterRacer(): 
      
    # Toplevel object which will  
    # be treated as a new window 
    racerWindow = Toplevel() 
    racerWindow['background']='#2A3132'
  
    # sets the title of the 
    # Toplevel widget 
    racerWindow.title("Enter New Racer") 
  
    # sets the geometry of toplevel 
    racerWindow.geometry("700x500") 
  
    # A Label widget to show in toplevel 
    Label(racerWindow, text ="Enter new racer window").pack()
    Label(racerWindow, text="First Name").pack()
    Label(racerWindow, text="Last Name").pack().grid(row=5)

    entry_1 = Entry(racerWindow)
    entry_1.pack()
    entry_1.grid(row=5)
```

When I run the app.py and I click on the "Enter New Racer" button I don't see any entry widget. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: i dont know if this is correct, but i have never seen `.pack().grid()` wat does it do? y are u packing it and then grid-ing it , just do one of it ? If im not wrong, you are not seeing your "Last Name" label too?

Comment: That could be a mistake but I can see all of the three labels. Only the entry widget is not showing. @CoolCloud

Comment: I immediately got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'`, you're mixing `pack` and `grid`, plus trying to do a `grid` on a already packed object.

Comment: do u want to place it or using grid? or just pack it?

Comment: Error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'`

Comment: You can only use `pack` OR `grid` in any given container, no mixing. You can have a Frame packed, then use grid inside it, or any other containers, but no mixing in any given container.

Comment: Okay so I removed the .grid() from the last label and the entry widget just showed up below the "last name". I think it went behind the label. Can anyone please explain? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Check my answer for some view of whats going on :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the issue here is that, you cannot do a combination of `.pack()` and `.grid()`. You will have to use one of them only.

You can change your function to this:

**For `.pack()`**

```
    # Toplevel object which will  
    # be treated as a new window 
    racerWindow = Toplevel() 
    racerWindow['background']='#2A3132'

    # sets the title of the 
    # Toplevel widget 
    racerWindow.title("Enter New Racer") 

    # sets the geometry of toplevel 
    racerWindow.geometry("700x500") 

    # A Label widget to show in toplevel 
    Label(racerWindow, text ="Enter new racer window").pack()
    Label(racerWindow, text="First Name").pack()
    Label(racerWindow, text="Last Name").pack()

    entry_1 = Entry(racerWindow)
    entry_1.pack()
```

**For `.grid()`**

```
def EnterRacer():
    # Toplevel object which will  
    # be treated as a new window 
    racerWindow = Toplevel() 
    racerWindow['background']='#2A3132'

    # sets the title of the 
    # Toplevel widget 
    racerWindow.title("Enter New Racer") 

    # sets the geometry of toplevel 
    racerWindow.geometry("700x500") 

    # A Label widget to show in toplevel 
    Label(racerWindow, text ="Enter new racer window").grid(row=0,column=0)
    Label(racerWindow, text="First Name").grid(row=0,column=1)
    Label(racerWindow, text="Last Name").grid(row=0,column=2)

    entry_1 = Entry(racerWindow)
    entry_1.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky=E+W)
```

This is just one way of grid-ing things, you can use youre own way by changing the row and column arguments. Let me know if any doubts :D

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to SO, happy coding :D